# why &p+1 give the same result as p

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
        int a[]= {15, 14, 34, 46, 69, 86, 10, 0, 4};
        int *p = a; // p point to the first element of array a[0]
        printf("%x\n%x\n",&p+1, &a[0]);
        return 0;
    }
```

that code will print as example

```
bff0e554
bff0e554
```

so &p+1 return the address of the first element of array.
As i understand, &p return the address of that pointer and &p+1 should print the address of pointer + 1 please tell me what i missed !!

Comment: An array is not a pointer is not an array. `&p` is the **address** of `p`.

Comment: Coincidence.  You're confusing `p+1` and `&p+1`.  It just so happens that `p` is stored such that one after `p` is the start of the array.  Reverse the order of the declarations, or introduce another array in between, or some other pointers, or almost anything that changes the layout of the variables on the stack and your printed values will no longer match – it's coincidence that they do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; It may be a coincidence, but you shouldn't ignore UB at this place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a funny one. Write down *precisely* what &p+1 means. It has nothing to do with any addresses in the array a. What it prints is pure coincidence.

Add another array b. Then set p = b and print &p + 1 and &b [0]. Maybe you figure out what happens.

Comment: as you and Kay says it's pure coincidence, i have declared the pointer first then the result has changed. btw (this was an exercice proposed by a teacher, he says that &p+1 == &a[0] in the solution -_-)

Comment: Tell your teacher to make `p` a global (while still letting `a` be a local) and have him explain why `&p+1` is nowhere in the vicinity of `a`. (Though first check what the teacher said, you may just find that you didn't interpret it correctly.)

Answer (score 6):

`&p` takes the address of `p`, not the value of `p`. That for you `&p + 1 == a` is pure coincidence and depends on your stack alignment. Your compiler could have sorted the both variables in another order or put a gap in between.

Comment: Actually there is not even a requirement to have a stack.

Answer (score 3):

An array is not a pointer is not an array.

`&p` is the address of `p`, not the address it contains (i.e. its value), which would be `p` (FYI: the value of the object it points to is `*p`). Similarly, `&a[0]` is the address of the first element in the array. It is pure coincidence the array is at the next address location (`&p +1`).

Additionally, the correct `printf` conversion-specifier for pointers is `%p` and it expects a `void *` (you are required to cast here, because that is a variadic function). Using a different specifier invokes undefined behaviour.

You should enable compiler warnings. Modern compilers will warn about such fundamental mismatches of types between the `printf` (and `scanf`) format strings and the arguments.

Comment: Nonsense. You're thinking of languages with a fancier memory model. In C, an array is simply a block of allocated memory. The address of the first element, and the address of the array are identical, and (modulo an edge condition with externs) `*(p+i) == a[i]`.

Comment: @CharlieMartin: I did not write anything else. For the question and my answer it does not even matter they are the same. However, e.g. `&a` and `&a[0]` are still different types, so it very well matters - just not here (and I do not even refer to this). I'm very confident I do know C very well and certainly did not have a "fancier memory model" in mind. How would you read this from the answer?

Comment: @CharlieMartin: But I appreciate unqualified downvotes. I'm not on your lawn!

Comment: @CharlieMartin: I'd really be interested to understand what you consider "*Nonsense*" with this answer?

Answer (score -3):

Check that you're running what you think you are. I just tried it, and it worked.

```
bash $ cc -o foo foo.c
foo.c:6:23: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type
      'int **' [-Wformat]
    printf("%x\n%x\n",&p+1, &a[0]);
            ~~        ^~~~
foo.c:6:29: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type
      'int *' [-Wformat]
    printf("%x\n%x\n",&p+1, &a[0]);
                ~~          ^~~~~
2 warnings generated.
bash $ ./foo
58af0888
58af0890
bash $
```

Observe the warnings, btw.

Comment: And yes, we just had a couple of downvotes for showing the results of compiling the code given.

Comment: Quite rectified. You did not address the UB, nor did you explain why **OP** sees the same value or why you don't.

Comment: @CharlieMartin the OP expects the first value to reveal the address of `a[1]` and the second to reveal the address of `a[0]`. The second value is explicit ground truth, but the first value should be the second value plus the size of an int... that's not the values you're getting.

Comment: I executed the program as he gave it, by copy and paste. I don't know what he's doing, but the program as written gives the results shown.

Comment: @CharlieMartin exactly. The results shown are clearly inappropriate for what he's posted he's trying to accomplish (which is not necessarily clear based on his choice of wording, but becomes more clear when analyzing why he might have accepted the answer he did). The OP was under the mistaken impression that `&p+1 == &a[1]`, which is not a reasonable position for him to have taken.